# Append div container with child elements to web page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, appendto

I'm trying to create a button that will dynamically add a div container to the webpage, and currently i'm doing that with code that looks like this inside a .click() event:

```
$("<div id = 'some_id'></div>").appendTo("#somecontainer");
```

which is working fine for now. However, I know that later on I will be adding more elements inside this div container (up to 3 or 4) so I'm wondering if there's a better, cleaner way to do this. Otherwise I'm thinking that my append statement will start to look something like this:

```
$("<div id = 'some_id'><div id = '1'><div id = '2'>...</div></div></div>").appendTo("#somecontainer");
```

which not only seems wrong, but is hard to structure. Any thoughts?

Edit: by the way, these child elements will end up being standard text/icons that are the same across all of these newly created containers, the only thing that is changing will be some inputted text inside.

Comment: your string literals are not proper `$('<div id = "some_id"></div>').appendTo("#somecontainer");`

Comment: Right, sorry that was a typo. It's correct in my code, and that's working fine. I was just wondering if there was something conceptually that I should be doing differently.

Comment: you can look at a templating library like [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanted to make it easier to edit in future, maybe break your various divs into separate objects then bring them together at the end

makes it very verbose but slightly easier to maintain

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var parent_container = $('<div id="1">Parent Container</div>'),
        section1 = $('<div id="2">Sub Section 1</div>'),
        subsection1 = $('<div id="3">Content within subsection 1</div>'),
        section2 = $('<div id="4">Sub Section 2</div>'),
        subsection2 = $('<div id="5">Content within subsection 2</div>');

    subsection1.appendTo(section1);
    section1.appendTo(parent_container);
    subsection2.appendTo(section2);
    section2.appendTo(parent_container);
    parent_container.appendTo("#somecontainer");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzp0fq2q/1/

Comment: alternative idea if you use coffeescript, since it has nice string interpolation http://jsfiddle.net/39rq9b04/2/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$("#some_id").appendTo("#somecontainer");
```

read documentation [**appendTo**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajadlfc/xotm505d/)

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajadlfc/vzdtkadx/)

Comment: But how would I get multiple div child elements inside that container?

Comment: @Phil you just give the id of the parent container

Comment: Right, but I don't want the parent container to show up anywhere in my HTML until the button is clicked, causing the function. Thus, how will I be able to place the child elements inside the container div?

Comment: Is there some way to do this using just CSS?

Comment: The thing is that the div container you created #some_id already exists in the original HTML file. I'm trying to create a new div container with child elements inside that isn't already present on the webpage. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead there is a way to append your DOM element into your container as shown in [This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/mxohw3s3/)

```
here I have just measured length of elements inside of Container & appending new DOM element based on its length/index
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should write a little function specific to your task: 'wrap x amount of divs with given ids in another div'

Your call would look something like this:

```
$makeElement(parentId,[id1,id2,id3]);
```

Your function might be :

```
$makeElement(pid,arr){
   var i=1,
        $p=$(pid);
    for(i; i<arr.length;i++){
        $p.append($(arr [i]));
    }
    return $p;
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
$('body')
    .append($makeElement('mybox','p1','p2'))
    .find('#p1')
    .append($makeElement('subbox','s1'));
```